# Fitch Notation Set Theory

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, logic-translation

I am wanting to show that $(A\cup B)-B\subseteq A$ by using Fitch Notation.
I think it would be as [follows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_GnvUal7VcdVF2cy1ndkJIUFU/view?usp=sharing). Would this be correct? I am unsure as to to label the assumption step and conditional introduction.
$$\def\ftc#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\ftc{}{\vdots\\\ftc{1.~(x\in A\lor x\in B)\land x\notin B\hspace{11ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{2.~(x\in A\lor x\in B)\hspace{20ex}\textsf{1, Simplification}\\3.~x\notin B\hspace{30.5ex}\textsf{1, Simplification}\\4.~x\in A\hspace{30.5ex}\textsf{2, 3, Disjunctive Sylogism}}\\5.~((x\in A\lor x\in B)\land x\notin B)\to x\in A\hspace{3.5ex}\textsf{1-4, Conditional Introduction}}$$

Comment: Yes, that all looks correct!

Comment: Is the assumption fine with the scope line without any preceding premises? That was one thing I was worried about. I apologize that it is a picture and not coded out. I would code it out, but those lines are hard to code.

Comment: @Bram28 I appreciate you looking at it!

Comment: Yes, you can start a proof with a subproof, that's fine. ... So you created this picture by hand, and not with a prover? In fact, Fitch systems typically only have INtroduction and Elimination rules, so do you have Disjunctive Syllogism available as a 1-step rule?

Comment: Yes, it is a pain. What is that? As for disjunctive syllogism as a one step rule, I just use this site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference

Comment: You mean what is a subproof?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59641/discussion-between-w-g-and-bram28).

Comment: @Bram28: Are you serious? Did you create a tag and then added 70+ questions to it in one day, without even bringing this to discussion, without waiting to see if anyone has any input? Are you kidding me???

Comment: @Bram28 I suppose you might have something to add to the discussion on meta about the new tag: [Can the tag (logic-translation) be useful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28150)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Hi, yes, thanks for letting me know! Sorry for all the trouble I caused, I feel pretty stupid :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I coded it up in the Fitch prover I like to use:

[image]

I used variables $y$ and $z$ instead of $A$ and $B$, so this proves it for any sets $A$ and $B$, but otherwise it is exactly your proof (and, as you can see by the checkmarks, the system accepted the proof!).  The $DS 2$ is Disjunctive Syllogism, proven elsewhere:

[image]

Please note though that different proof systems have different rules, so in a different system than the one I use here, the proof may look slightly different (e.g. not every system uses the explicit contradiction symbol $\bot$)

Comment: Whats the name of that prover? If its free I wouldn't mind downloading it myself.

Comment: @user400188 It's aptly named 'Fitch', but it's not free. It comes with the commercial book and software package called 'Language, Proof, and Logic'.